# Issue : when i click Payment Methods tab all the page is keep loading in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, payment-gateway

In My admin panel when i click the **Payment Methods** section the entire page is loading.The loading is not stopping.**Payment Services** tab is working fine.Any one faced this issue here before.Expecting your advice regarding this.

I Noticed this after i installed a **Stripe payment** module.So i remove this and check the same thing happening.So my issue is not because of stripe payment gateway module.

**UPDATE**

Browser console error.
[image]

Comment: first enable error log and then check error log also check console for error too you will get the error and paste that here.

Comment: no any error logs created

Comment: what about browser console when ajax call making anything their?

Comment: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING its giving this error and keep loading

Comment: remove the jquery and then check maybe conflict of jquery

Comment: i removed the entire extension.But still its keep loading

Comment: thanks  @QaisarSatti.
 its because of my antivirus security.After disabling the antivirus the loading i sstoped

Comment: after all you google the error by yourself good.

Comment: Hi @QaisarSatti any possibility to help in this question if you have time http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157137/how-to-create-a-copy-of-catalog-manage-products-in-a-new-menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me its because of my **antivirus** in the laptop.If any one face this same issue try to **disable the antivirus** and check.may be this will help you to over come this issue.