# How to create a copy of catalog-> manage products in a new menu?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid, products-management

**Magento version 1.9**

I want to create a copy of manage product in a new menu in magento admin.
I created the menu and i am struck with copying the product view grid and rest of the thing.Can any one help me please to achieve this task.

**My config.xml file**

```
<config>  
<modules> 
    <Eight25media_Tproducts> 
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Eight25media_Tproducts>
</modules>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <tproducts>
            <class>Eight25media_Tproducts_Helper</class>
        </tproducts>
    </helpers>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>             
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <tproducts>Eight25media_Tproducts_Adminhtml</tproducts>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

**My adminhtml.xml file**

```
<config>  
<menu>
    <tproducts translate="title" module="tproducts">
        <title>Products - Training</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
            <manage_tproducts>
                <title>Manage Products(Training) </title>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/catalog_product/</action>
            </manage_tproducts>
        </children>
    </tproducts>
</menu>
```

For now, i just called the **catalog_product** link. But i want to call in my own frontend name.

How can i implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing `after="Mage_Adminhtml"` in **config.xml**

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>             
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <tproducts after="Mage_Adminhtml">Eight25media_Tproducts_Adminhtml</tproducts>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

then simply call the `<action>adminhtml/controllername_actionname/</action>`

simply extends your grid block with all grid will be loaded

```
 class Eight25media_Tproducts_Block_Adminhtml_Tproducts_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid 
{


}
```

now all the action will goes to your controller

you want to just add the block nothing to change just add this xml in your layout

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product" name="products_list">
                <block type="adminhtml/store_switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher">
                    <action method="setUseConfirm"><params>0</params></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
```

Comment: Thank you.
I can view the menu.My question is how to make a clone of catalog ->manage products

Comment: @mujas you want to show the product grid?

Comment: yes under my link name as well as all actions related to product.

Comment: here is you can do create the your grid container and then your grid and extends your grid  with magento product grid. hope this will work for you.

Comment: can you pleas explain this as an answer,i ave no clue or idea to implement.Great help

Comment: @mujas i added the example in answer follow that.

Comment: i did the same but i am redirected to 404 page

Comment: it is related to your admin url that are not working check with that what is problem their.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52787/discussion-between-mujas-and-qaisar-satti).